# Javascript - drawRect está interferindo na cor de fundo

Tags: javascript, canvas

Quando eu ponho um **quadrado** na **canvas** o **fundo** fica branco.

```js
(function(){
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  var fps = 30;
  var height = 300;
  var width = 300;
  var Bloco = new bloco();
  c.width = 300;
  c.height = 300;
  document.body.appendChild(c)

  setInterval(draw(), 1000/fps)

  function draw(){
    background("black");

    Bloco.put();

  }
  function bloco(x, y, size, color){
    this.size = size;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;

    this.put = function(){
      quadrado(10, 10, 10, "white");
    }
  }
  function quadrado(x, y, size, color){
    ctx.rect(x, y, size+x, size+y);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
  function background(color){
    ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
```

Eu queria saber como faço para desenhar um **quadrado** sem inteferir na cor do **fundo**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de iniciar cada desenho/caminho, é necessário chamar o método [*beginPath()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) para "esvaziar" a lista de caminhos, caso contrário, o comando *fill* irá preencher o canvas com o caminho anterior (*background*).

O código fica da seguinte forma:

```
function quadrado(x, y, size, color){
    ctx.beginPath(); // AQUI: Colocar o beginPath()
    ctx.rect(x, y, size+x, size+y);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
}

function background(color){
    ctx.beginPath(); // AQUI: Colocar o beginPath()
    ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Veja funcionando: [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/gomiero/5j284pzj/)